# Why does Presidio StanzaNlpEngine throw NameError: name 'StanzaLanguage' is not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stanza, presidio

I'm trying to use Stanza language models with Presidio and running into this blocker.

```
import stanza
stanza.download("en")

from presidio_analyzer.nlp_engine import StanzaNlpEngine
StanzaNlpEngine(models={"en": "en"})
```

Above throws...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../presidio_analyzer/nlp_engine/stanza_nlp_engine.py", line 41, in __init__
    for lang_code, model_name in models.items()
  File ".../presidio_analyzer/nlp_engine/stanza_nlp_engine.py", line 41, in <dictcomp>
    for lang_code, model_name in models.items()
NameError: name 'StanzaLanguage' is not defined
```

This seems like this should work, looking at [the code](https://github.com/microsoft/presidio/blob/ba994de68faf64aca857c3794954e209c4d6a165/presidio-analyzer/presidio_analyzer/nlp_engine/stanza_nlp_engine.py#L29).

Even this throws the same error.

```
StanzaNlpEngine()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was [fixed in version 2.2.2](https://github.com/microsoft/presidio/pull/711):

> the Spacy-Stanza interface had changed in spaCy 3. This PR proposes:
>
> 1. The fix to the spacy-stanza interface.
> 2. Bug fix on getting the right recognizer given the nlp engine (`SpacyRecognizer` for `SpancyNlpEngine` and `StanzaRecognizer` for
>    `StanzaNlpEngine`)
> 3. Bug fix in the decision process string for Stanza